# The sidebar of this website keeps falling to the bottom of the page - issue in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, sidebar

The website in question looks great in Chrome/Firefox, but all kinds of messed up in IE9.

I tried adding this line of code to the header.php file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

I also checked the padding to see if that is causing an issue... I couldn't find where it was.

I checked all my plugins to see if one of them was disruptive. That wasn't the case.

I used this validator (http://validator.w3.org/) to find errors in the code, but there weren't very many at all.

I have **no** idea how to fix this one. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: so.......... what line of code did you try adding?

Comment: oops meant to paste - <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

Comment: `X-UA-Compatible` must be before any of style definitions in the page. Now it has no effect, place it right after the `head` tag.

Comment: You say there weren't many validation errors, but I wouldn't be surprised if some of them were confusing IE, particularly the closing comment tags.  Comments should be closed with -->, not --!>; meaning some of your closing tags might be treated as being within comments, and so not closing as you'd expect.  I'd start by fixing the validation errors.

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you for your assistance. I fixed some of the comments, but the issue still remains... do you have any other thoughts? I also tried adding the X-UA-Compatible line below the </head> and it didn't work out...

Comment: It's resolved! I think it was actually placing the X-UA-Compatible after the </head> that made it work - had to clear cache. Thanks for all of your help! :)